# Call PyMOL wizard

Tags: python, wxpython, pymol

I would like to call one of the wizards from PyMOL menu in my python script. My script is python code which uses wx library. Does anybody knows if it is possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so depending of what wizard you wanted to use, you might be better off simply calling the underlying commands.

For example, if you wanted to use the distance wizard, you would probably be better off simply calling the `distance` command. See: http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Distance

On the other hand, to try and use the wizards directly, you can call
    `pymol.cmd.wizard("annotation")`

where 'annotation' is the name of the wizard you want.
For more information, see http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Annotation_wizard

Comment: Thanks, Matt! I would like to call the "user" wizard, i.e. python script that works as a wizard in PyMOL. When I tried to run:

cmd.wizard("name"),

I have got the error:

"Sorry, couldn't import the 'name' wizard."

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do a little more? Are you trying to create your own wizard, or use one of the existing ones?  If you are using an existing one, you can run 'help wizard' to see the list of available wizards.

Comment: PyMOL menu contains sections 'Wizard' and 'Plugin'. My collegue wrote the python script which works as a wizard in PyMOL. It can be launched by selecting it in the 'Wizard' list. I wrote another python script which can be launched from 'Plugin' list. These two scripts work well together (at the same time). Now I would like to be able to call this wizard from my script. But when I try to call it: cmd.wizard(MtsslWizard), the PyMOL shows the message: "NameError: name 'MtsslWizard' is not defined."

Comment: Ok, what I think that you need to do (I haven't tested), is to call: `wiz = MtsslWizard()` and then `cmd.set_wizard(wiz)`.  Where MtsslWizard is your wizard class.

Comment: Matt, you have not understood me. I do not have MtsslWizard class in my script, I'd like just to call it (or better to say whole script of MtsslWizard) from my script.

Comment: Are you importing the MtsslWizard into your script? If you are, then you should be able to do what I just said with a slight modification: `import MtsslWizard` then `wiz = MtsslWizard.MtsslWizard()`, and finally `cmd.set_wizard(wiz)`.  If I am still not understanding, could you edit your original question with some example code?

Comment: Thanks, Matt! This is what I need! It is also important to determine the path to the MtsslWizard file: sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) +'\mtsslWizard_classes.py')

Comment: Glad I could help! If that is all you needed, you can mark the question as answered.